# how to regenerate ios and android folder in flutter - i want to rename the project name (com.example.projectname)

Tags: flutter

I want to regenerate ios and android folder in flutter.

Is there a way to do it after deleting those folder ?

Reason is I want to rename the project name (com.example.projectname), as a different variant than the original.

Comment: At first backup your project folde, would you try to like this?
move to project folder and type `flutter create .` command

Comment: do you have a solution ?

Comment: Sometimes when I want to change package name, I just search all project name in the source and replace to new package name.

Comment: it appears to be quite a lot of files

Comment: Hm... When I searched, there are bout 5 files related to package name.

Comment: i found this https://pub.dev/packages/rename. anyway back to original question then how to regenerate ios and android folder

Comment: Please check first comment. ```flutter create .```

Comment: @Axil would [Flutter Flavours](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors) be a better option for the requirements?

Comment: @dev-aentgs, thanks a lot for flavours, this might be perfect for this. single code source rather than duplicating project

Answer (score 0):

To change your applicationId for an Android Application.
Run the command in the command terminal.

flutter pub global run rename --bundleId com.example.projectname